# How to insert the information of a cookie in a form

Tags: php, html, cookies

I have a problem with my php script. I would like to print the value of my cookie, as "value" in the form I have created. But it does not print it and my website does not look like I want. Here is my code. And the error I got is:
Notice: Undefined index: pseudo in C:\xampp\htdocs\OpenClassroom\index.php on line 4

Thanks in advance.

```html
<?php
if (isset($_COOKIE['username']))
{
    setcookie('username', htmlspecialchars($_POST['pseudo']), time() + 31536000, null, null, false, true);
}
else
{
    setcookie('username', 'NewUsername', time() + 365*24*3600, null, null, false, true);
}
?>
    
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Mini-chat</title>
    </head>
    <style>
    form
    {
        text-align:center;
    }
    </style>
    <body>
    <!--Form-->
    <form action="commentaires.php" method="post">
        <p>
        <label for="pseudo">Pseudo</label> : <input type="text" value="<?php echo $_COOKIE['username'] ; ?>" name="pseudo" id="pseudo" /><br />
        <label for="message">Message</label> :  <input type="text" name="message" id="message" /><br />

        <input type="submit" value="Envoyer" />
 </p>
    </form>
```

Comment: What are the errors you get after enabling the `error_reporting(E_ALL);`. Are the cookies set? Check this in your browser

Comment: I have this error: Notice: Undefined index: pseudo in C:\xampp\htdocs\OpenClassroom\index.php on line 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$_COOKIE` doesn't set the cookie when using `setcookie()` on the first request according to the documentation:

> Once the cookies have been set, they can be accessed on the next page load with the $_COOKIE array. Cookie values may also exist in $_REQUEST.

So...subsequent requests will show properly. A quick and dirty solution is to set it manually the first time:

```
<?php
if (isset($_COOKIE['username']))
{
    setcookie('username', htmlspecialchars($_POST['pseudo']), time() + 31536000, null, null, false, true);
}
else
{
    setcookie('username', 'NewUsername', time() + 365*24*3600, null, null, false, true);
    $_COOKIE['username'] = 'NewUsername';
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your help. I did what you said and now I have a starter cookie, but when I change my "pseudo", the cookie is supposed to change and it does not. Could you please help me?

Comment: There we some other issues with the code. Full conversation can be found [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144628/conversation-between-pnb-and-frankerz)